# Case of multiple viewports in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a folder which will contain many pages/applications. One such application is called `dynamics`. So the folder structure now looks like this:

```
- dynamics.js
+ model
+ view
  - Viewport.js
  - Dynamics.js
+ controller
```

So, as you can see, I now have only one page/application, but in future I will have a lot of them. Because of that, I do not want to use standard `Viewport.js` file, but `Dynamics.js`. However, if I configure `application` like this:

```
Ext.application({
  ...
  autoCreateViewport:'Dynamics'
});
```

I get a blank page, even though `Dynamics.js` (which is identical to `Viewport.js`) is loaded. So, I need some help, guys.

**EDIT**

Did it. I just created a custom viewport inside application itself and used `autoCreateViewport:false`.

Comment: create a fiddle that shows the problem please.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is so necessary. The idea is simple - how to use custom view and configure application? The simplest task, I think.

Comment: @pherris If you have a running example where you use some custom view instead of Viewport.js, then you are welcome. I will definitely upvote your answer

Comment: Are Dynamics and Viewport exactly the same? - they both define the same class name? Also, the autoCreateViewport property is a boolean (doesnt take a string) http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-autoCreateViewport which by convention loads the App.view.Viewport in app/view/Viewport.js - I'm guessing your string is interpreted as truthy and you are loading Viewport.js, but it's hard to say without a fiddle :)

Comment: Well, that is the case. You may not look and wonder at how I did. Because what I did is incorrect. Imagine, I do not have standard `Viewport.js` file in `view` folder, but just a bunch of custom views, that I would like to associate with particular pages/applications (like `dynamics.js`). How would you configure `Ext.application` in this case?... As for your question, then - yes, they define the same class, that is why `Dynamics.js` at least is loaded (though does not have any effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single application page (index.html), try something similar to this.  Then you can define your default viewport class (Viewport.js) differently from the second viewport class (Dynamics.js).

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    extend: 'MyApp.Application',
    autoCreateViewport: false,
    launch: function () {

                if (window.location.href.indexOf('/MyApp/index.html') > -1) {
                        Ext.create('MyApp.view.Viewport');
                }
                else if (window.location.href.indexOf('/MyApp/index.html?viewport=Dynamics') > -1) {
                        Ext.create('MyApp.view.Dynamics');
                }
    }
});
```